# Using C# HttpClient, how to POST a string HttpContent to ASP.net Core web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

On client side, I Post a request using `HttpClient` class to an ASP.net core web API on server side.

I want to send a string (`"OK"`) in the body of the request, and a string argument (`numStr=5`) in the header, I've read many similar thread but still failed.

Here is the Client Method:

```
public async void SendBodyAsync(Action<string> onRespond)
{
    try
    {
        string URL = "http://localhost:60039/api/calculator/AddMore";

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, URL);
        request.Headers.Add("numStr", "5");

        request.Content = new StringContent("OK", Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");   //causes error

        HttpResponseMessage response = await mHttpClient.SendAsync(request);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        onRespond(result);
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        Debug.LogError(ex);       //Unity3D console Debug
        onRespond(null);
    }
}
```

Here is the Server Action:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class CalculatorController : ControllerBase
{
    public string AddMore([FromHeader]string numStr)
    {
        //string bodyStr;
        //get string from Request.Body and set the value to bodyStr
        return (int.Parse(numStr) + 10).ToString();
    }
}
```

If I remove the line `request.Content = new StringContent("OK", Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");` from the client method, the respond value is `15` which is correct.

But with the `request.Content`, the client shows the error:

> An error occurred while sending the request --->
> System.Net.WebException: The request requires buffering data to
> succeed.

The server break point is not triggered, so the request was not sent out successfully.

I have created another very simple server method using `HttpListener`, it reads the `request.Content` as `clientContext` stream correctly. I think maybe the problem is that `request.Content` is not equal to Http body, and it's unlikely a buffering issue as the error message says.

My questions are,

1. How to send a string in Http body correctly, it's not argument and can be long (like a complete player profile in string format), so it's not proper for header or query or...
2. How can I receive and parse the string in the request body on server side correctly?

Thank you so much for reading my post.

Comment: Was the problem resolved?

Comment: I just re-created the server project, and it worked, no change was made, I don't why. But anyway thanks for reading my thread. I guess people who see the same error message can try re-creating the project. Hope it helps.

Comment: That's great, you can post how did you overcome it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your AddMore method. I think you should also get the body content using the *[FromBody] string parameter* as well, I do not see it specified.

Note also if you do not specify accept/content type it is by default application/json in .NET core

P.S Also consider making your AddMore method an async method

Comment: Thank you for your advice, now since the client no longer give error (simply re-created the server project), I added, on server side, a StreamReader to read stream from Request.Body, and stream.ReadToEndAsync() to get the string. Since I have to "await" stream.ReadToEndAsync(), thus I have to mark the method as "async Task<string>". My further question is that with the "await" in the method, if the method is described as "async Task<string>", the method won't block the main thread when many clients are calling this method, is that right? Many instances of the method will run asynchronously?

Comment: hi @solidcomer yes that is correct, by using async task<string> you will not be blocking your main UI thread ( in the case of a WPF app for example).freeing up your application to handle other requests, under a huge load this will assist in minimizing "thread starvation", here is a nicely written article on it for reference.  https://coderjony.com/blogs/what-is-thread-starvation-in-aspnet-applications/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I can't editor my own thread. Just want to say I re-created a project and pasted the same code, and it worked.
Maybe people who see the error message "An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: The request requires buffering data to succeed" can try the same.
Hope it helps.